# Object Storage vs HDD Block Storage

Tags: performance, digital-ocean, hdd, vultr, object-storage

Currently I am using SSD Block Storage at Digital Ocean which is very costly. When I checked Vultr they are providing HDD Block Storage. Which is cheap.

We have to store approx 700GB of data (Mostly images) and serve them on websites.

Should we use Digital Ocean Spaces behind DO Virtual Machine or "Vultr Server+HDD Block Storage" behind DO Virtual Machine?

Which will provide better performance?

You can better understand from the following diagram:

[image: Which is better plan for cost cutting?]

Purpose of Cloudflare Cache to reduce the bandwidth usage of Vultr VM instance.
On both plans we will cache images on Digital Ocean VM's SSD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the price difference is mainly due to the cost/performance of SSD vs HDD. Whether HDDs are fast enough depends on the *rate that you're serving those images*. The amount of data you store isn't really relevant.

Roughly, a single HDD can serve around 80-200 4K requests/second (IOPS), from cheap 7200 RPM SATA to 15,000 RPM SAS. In an array, you can ideally multiply that by the number of drives. In cloud HDD storage, you may expect maybe 1000 IOPS.

A single, modern SSD serves around 50,000 to 500,000 IOPS, so there's a vast difference in performance, but also in price.

Comment: My question is "Vultr VM+HDD" vs "Object Storage". See the above diagram.

Comment: We will cache frequently requested images in Cloudflare cache and Digital Ocean SSD Cache.

Comment: Since you have mentioned neither what the peak throughput is nor what the planned cache size is, you can only expect a general answer - "it depends".